# Need Sample Code to display more than one widget(widget size is equal to frame) in Fixed Size Frame using Scroll Bar in QT

Tags: c++, qt

I want to display more than one widget (my widget's size is equal to the frame size) in a Fixed Size Frame using a Scroll Bar in QT.
Please suggest how I can achieve this.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I know this is your first question, but if you take a look at how other questions with up votes are structured, you will notice that people usually provide a little more context to the question, and also some code snippets helping to illustrate what they are working with. That being said... what does your current structure look like (concise example please). That way we can try and identify what aspect might be incorrect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The QScrollArea class provides a scrolling view onto another widget.If the widget exceeds the size of the frame, the view can provide scroll bars so that the entire area of the child widget can be viewed.

You can layout several widget on a parent widget, than set the parent widget into a QScrollArea.

A example is provided with QtSDK in path

```
examples/widgets/imageviewer
```